# Is it possible to iterate over quote line items in HTML template instead of using type of content Line Items?

Tags: cpq, quote-template

I'm trying to add a background color to the table that displays the line items for a CPQ quote, but if I select the Line Items type, there is not a ton of changes I can do there.
Can I select instead HTML as the type and use some type of logic to iterate over the quote line items and print them?
I would use the HTML functionality to add a background color the the table.
[image]

These are the options displayed if I select Line items, there are not a ton of changes I can do there.
[image]

Would like to see it like the table above with a blue background instead of plain white.
[image]